# C++ including functional header gives error '__dest' does not name a type

Tags: c++

I have a C++ that used to work. However, after including the `<functional>` header, compilation fails with the message

```
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\std_function.h: In static member function 'static void std::_Function_base::_Base_manager<_Functor>::_M_clone(std::_Any_data&, const std::_Any_data&, std::true_type)':
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\std_function.h:167:11: error: '__dest' does not name a type
  167 |    ::new (__dest._M_access()) _Functor(__source._M_access<_Functor>());
      |           ^~~~~~
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\std_function.h:167:17: error: expected ')' before '.' token
  167 |    ::new (__dest._M_access()) _Functor(__source._M_access<_Functor>());
      |          ~      ^
      |                 )
```

I am using MinGW GCC 8.2.0, but it also occurs with version 9.2.0.

Answer (score 8):

This was part of a test suite. It turns out that the error was caused by CppUTest doing operator overloading. The overloads were included using `-include/path/to/MemoryLeakDetectorNewMacros.h` so it was not directly obvious from looking at just the code.

Solution for when using CppUTest: make sure that the C++ STL header is included before the CppUTest header `MemoryLeakDetectorNewMacros.h`. See the [CppUTest manual](https://cpputest.github.io/manual.html) section "Resolving conflicts with STL" for more information.